# Как можно получить координаты угла блока?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть блок, нужно получить координаты его угла, как можно это сделать?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: вот пример https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816503/how-get-real-positions-of-element-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const someBlock = document.querySelector('.some-block');

const rectSomeBlock = someBlock.getBoundingClientRect();

console.log('Координаты левого верхнего угла:' + 'x= ' + rectSomeBlock.x + ' | y= ' + rectSomeBlock.y);
console.log('Координаты левого нижнего угла:' + 'x= ' + rectSomeBlock.x + ' | y= ' + rectSomeBlock.bottom);
console.log('Координаты правого верхнего угла:' + 'x= ' + rectSomeBlock.right + ' | y= ' + rectSomeBlock.y);
console.log('Координаты правого нижнего угла:' + 'x= ' + rectSomeBlock.right + ' | y= ' + rectSomeBlock.bottom);
```

```css
.some-block {
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid red;
  /*Можете поочерёдно расскоментировать данные внешние отступы, чтобы просмотреть, как это работает*/
  /*margin-left: 20px;*/
  /*margin-top: 20px;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="some-block">Какой-то блок</div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect - а вот здесь более подробно почитать можно